# Почему electron выдает ошибку

Tags: node.js, electron

[image: скриншот]

Почему выходит ошибка и в консоль не выводится фраза "index.js is loaded"?

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css">
    <script src="./js/index.js"></script>
</head>
```

Код main.js:

```
// подключение Electron.JS
const { app, BrowserWindow}= require("electron");

function createWindow() {
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1920,
        height: 1080,
        frame: false,
        title: "Discord",
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            enableRemoteModule: true
        }
    });

    // загрузка index.html
    win.loadFile("index.html");

    // загрузка Dev Tools
    win.webContents.openDevTools();
}

// создание окна
app.whenReady().then(createWindow);

app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
    if(process.platform !== "darwin") {
        app.quit();
    }
});

// проверка на наличие открытых окон
app.on("activate", () => {
    // если открытых окон нет, то создаем окно
    if(BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow();
    }
})
```

Код index.js:

```
const remote = require("electron").remote;
const wnd = remote.getCurrentWindow();

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    console.log("index.js is loaded");
});
```

Comment: наверное, потому что, файл index.js выполняется в среде браузера, а не NodeJs

Comment: И что тогда делать? Как исправить ошибку? В документации пишут, что remote следует заменить на ipcMain, ipcRenderer.

Comment: @win так ведь правильно пишут, даже минимальный [пример установки канала сообщений](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main)

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решается добавлением contextIsolation: false в webPreferences

```
webPreferences: {
   nodeIntegration: true,
   enableRemoteModule: true,
   contextIsolation: false
}
```